# Lucky Triples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44935955/3058609) on Stack Overflow, I decided to stretch my legs in Haskell a bit to see if I could implement a solution to find the count of lucky triples in a list of ints.

A lucky triple is any triple `(j, k, l)` where `j <= k <= l` and `` l `mod` k == 0 && k `mod` j == 0 ``. A correct implementation counts how many unique combinations of elements of an `[Int]` are valid lucky triples.

```
import Data.List (sort)

answer :: [Int] -> Int
answer xs = foldr ((+) . foldr ((+) . length) 0) 0 $ twoStepFactors
  where
    twoStepFactors = map mapFactors $ mapFactors $ sort xs

mapFactors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
mapFactors xs = mapFactors' xs []
mapFactors' [] acc = acc
mapFactors' (x:xs) acc = mapFactors' xs newAcc 
  where
    factors = filter ((==0) . (`mod` x)) xs
    newAcc | null factors = acc
           | otherwise = acc ++ [factors]
```

Comment: `answer` could also be `sum $ map sum $ map (map length) twoStepFactors` but I'm not sure that's better!!

Answer (score 3):

If `mapFactors'` is put in a where clause of `mapFactors`, it isn't globally accessible and you can call it `go` or something because the scoping already points out it belongs to `mapFactors`.

Swapping `go`s argument order lets you say `mapFactors = go []`.

`++ [_]` is a smell. Instead of passing down an `acc`umulator and growing it to the right, you can pass it out as the return value and grow it to the left.

```
mapFactors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
mapFactors = go where
  go [] = []
  go (x:xs) = newAcc $ go xs where
    factors = filter ((==0) . (`mod` x)) xs
    newAcc | null factors = id
           | otherwise = (:) factors
```

The filtering can happen after `go` is done.

```
mapFactors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
mapFactors = filter (not . null) . go where
  go [] = []
  go (x:xs) = filter ((==0) . (`mod` x)) xs : go xs
```

`tails` helps express `go` in terms of `map`:

```
mapFactors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
mapFactors = filter (not . null) . map go . tails where
  go [] = []
  go (x:xs) = filter ((==0) . (`mod` x)) xs
```

Let's use `sum` from that comment and inline the once-used `twoStepFactors` (imo if you're only giving a name to explain what something does, use comments)

```
answer :: [Int] -> Int
answer xs = sum $ map (sum . map length . mapFactors) $ mapFactors $ sort xs
```

There doesn't seem to be a reason to filter out the `[]`s.

List comprehensions neatly let us skip the empty tail, and get rid of `go`.

```
mapFactors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
mapFactors xss = [filter ((==0) . (`mod` x)) xs | x:xs <- tails xss]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the point of `sort` or `mapFactors`. The relationship between `j` and `l` is just the transitive relationship through `k`, so the total number of lucky triples is the sum over `k` of (number of `j` which work with this `k`) times (number of `l` which work with this `k`). Emphasis on *number of*: there's no need to generate an `[Int]` or to count them in any particular order.

Comment: `sort`ing once allows me to find products without searching the entire list, saving me an n^2 run over the list. I'm not sure how to implement the algorithm you outline (and not completely sure I understand what you mean by "sum over `k`"), but I think you mean to count the factors of each element present in the list, subtract one from that (since `k` will always be a factor of `k`), then multiply that by itself less one? I'm not sure that's correct, since it implies that no two factors would be co-prime which is obviously false.

Comment: e.g. in the list `[1..6]`, evaluating 6 would give factors `[6, 3, 2, 1]`. Applying that algorithm would seem to give 6 pairs: `[(3, 1), (2, 1)]` which are accurate, but also `[(3, 2)]` which are co-prime, and all their inverses `[(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]`

Comment: It still looks n^2 to me, and in fact I think it has to be: consider the extreme case where all the elements of the list are equal. [Python implementation](https://tio.run/##bVBLDoMgEN17itk0gdYm4LKJJzEuNGKL2tEgxnp6OvhrjH0r3oc3DN1kXy1GzhWqhAz7URnW8EcABIQYGoXEZ1qORQh5TWIiUrgChtthsVsDGjSCyfCpGK4lHh9flOh0F3y2@p/1mOZ8lR5EXVLPxXsxiGN@fR1NgFsM8uTlNZX9LKPsYBD64c0YW@/dQXJahVF0Y6eFOA@Czmi0@0fp3rLFlSFEQkjKOPcF) to show what I mean.

Comment: Your implementation doesn't handle duplicate numbers well. Try `answer([1,1,1])` (which should be one, since `(1, 1, 1)` is itself a lucky triple). Regardless in a sorted list you only need to compare each element of index `j` with elements of index `>j`. No element of index `<=j` can be a valid product (except itself, but that's double-dipping!)

Comment: That's an ambiguity in the spec. I'm treating the elements as distinguishable, or counting ordered tuples (i, j, k) for which L[i] divides L[j] divides L[k].

Comment: Ah, no, I see the problem. I'm also counting some tuples (i, j, i) when L[i] = L[j]